disable new line at EOF in GO extension in vscode
i have a problem that when i'm editing a big .go file and saving it then formatter is automatically adding a new line at the end of file, which is for some reason causes my cursor to move to somewhere near end of the file (happens only with big files). i tried different things and found out that this is caused by Go extension and it's formatting rules. how do i disable it?
i already tried:

disabling files.insertFinalNewline (was already disabled)
changing formatting tool to default, gofmt and goimports

thinking about turning off formatting on save, but maybe theres a better way?
edit: maybe it's not because of adding a new line, but it's definitely because of the Go extension
